# Swig - nodejs - using whitespace

Tags: node.js, swig-template

When using Swig (v.1.2.2) I am having trouble trying to use an object with keys that contain a white space.

For instance, how do I use the following object in a Swig template?

```
{ _lang: 'english',
Title: 'This is the title',
Sub_title: 'This is the sub title',
Feature_1: 'This is the feature 1',
'Feature 2': 'This is the feature 2',
'Feature 3': 'This is the feature 3',
'Feature 4': 'This is the feature 4',
'Feature 5': 'This is the feature 5',
'Feature 6': 'This is the feature 6',
Footer: 'This is the footer' }
```

So, for all of the keys without whitespace, i can use them easily with something like:

```
<p> {{Feature_1}}</p>
```

How do I do something similar for Feature 2, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported unless you nest those items one-level deep:

```
{
    Title: 'This is the title',
    Features: {
        'Feature 1': 'This is the feature 1',
        'Feature 2': 'This is the feature 2',
        'Feature 3': 'This is the feature 3',
        'Feature 4': 'This is the feature 4',
        'Feature 5': 'This is the feature 5',
        'Feature 6': 'This is the feature 6',
    }
}
```

Then you can access like this:

```
<p>{{ Features['Feature 1'] }}</p>
```

Or loop:

```
{% for key,feature in Features %}
    <p>{{ feature }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, as a general rule-of-thumb, it's widely considered faster and easier to use keys that are dot-notation-accessible (don't require quotes).

Comment: By dot notation you mean simple names right, because if you use a key with dots, it will get quoted as well (so as not to be confused with a field of an object). And that's kind of a bummer as well, you won't be able to use it for localization purposes where the key is the full text in english, that was the whole idea... do you know any other templating system for node that would be able to do that?